# Как корректно вызвать деструктор

Tags: c++

Возможно, вопрос довольно глупый, но я что-то не могу понять как корректно вызвать деструктор при таком выделении памяти:

```
Class_Name* arr[3];
arr[0] = new Class();
arr[1] = new Class(2);
arr[2] = new Class(3, 3);
```

Вот так:

```
delete[] arr;
```

Или так:

```
for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    delete arr[i];
```

Или вообще как-то по-другому ?

Comment: Три конструктора- три деструктора. Конечно второй вариант.

Comment: @nick_n_a спасибо. оформите как ответ ?

Comment: Используйте умный указатель.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если бы вы вызвали так : `Class * * arr = new Class * [ 3 ] ;`, и потом выделяли память :

```
arr[0] = new Class();
arr[1] = new Class(2);
arr[2] = new Class(3, 3);
```

то сначала нужно опять циклом освобождать память :

```
for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
  delete arr[i];
```

а потом ещё освобождать память от трёх указателей с помощью `delete [ ] arr ;`. Эта команда сначала вызовет деструктор трёх указателей (*то есть ничего не будет делать, так как у указателей нет деструкторов*), а потом освободит память от них.

Так как у вас массив скорее всего в стеке, то от этого массива освобождать память вручную не надо, и останется только циклом удалить объекты `arr[i]` из свободной памяти.

```
for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
  delete arr[i];
```